# C# Autofac- System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface

Tags: c#, autofac

```
---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor()' on type 'Application`1'.
---> System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface.
```

I am trying to register two implementations using Autofac but I am getting the error above.
I have generic classes which I registered

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ClassA<>)).As(typeof(IClassA<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ClassB<,>)).As(typeof(IClassB<,>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

The ClassA implentation on Controller look like this:

```
private readonly IClassA<IClassB<OtherA, OtherB>> _classA;
public ClassController(IClassA<IClassB<OtherA, OtherB>> classA){
    _classA = classA;
}
```

Anybody can help me with this or am I missing something?

Comment: What the constructors of `ClassA` and `ClassB` look like? `ClassA` is `Application1`?

Comment: I suspect one type was registered wrong, might have registered interface as type, not type as interface. It could be that `Application` class.

Comment: What is `Application<T>` ?

Comment: @weichch and Cyril Durand, nevermind the Application replace it with ClassA. Originally I just changed the Application name for it but it is the same.

Comment: could you `ClassA` are you sure it is a class and not an interface ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand Yes that's right, its coming there, I found out the error using the Autofac. I am trying to reinitialize the instance if null but the fact that it was already in a factory itself. It should not be initialized in generics.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to my question that in Autofac, we should not initialize manually the class we are referencing to interface because it will generate this kind of error. The fact that it is autowired with the properties and no need to reinitialized. I remove the checking If Instance == null then I will create new ClassA to supply the Instance.